# Error while trying to install nodemon with Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, npm-install, nodemon

When I try to install nodemon with `npm install -g nodemon` it gives me the following error:

```
'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226745/npm-warn-notsup-skipping-optional-dependency-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents)

Comment: tried that but in the end it gives the same error and doesn't let me use nodmon saying `'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Did you run it in the index directory where you installed nodemon in? Try installing again using `npm i --s nodemon`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. And yes it was installed in the index directory

Comment: yes it works thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a problem, as it had said, it's an *optional* dependency, so you don't really need it. Please refer to these answers below:

- [How to solve npm install throwing fsevents warning on non-MAC OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929196/how-to-solve-npm-install-throwing-fsevents-warning-on-non-mac-os)
- [How to fix 'Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103865/how-to-fix-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents1-2-9-wanted-osdarwin-arch)
- [npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226745/npm-warn-notsup-skipping-optional-dependency-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents)
- [npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189422/npm-warn-optional-skipping-optional-dependency-fsevents1-2-7)

Comment: tried it but still doesnt let me use nodmeon. Saying its an unrecognized file or something

Comment: Try reinstalling nodemon or adding it directly to your `package.json` and use `npm install`.

Comment: Already tried that